# Page not found on custom post type page for projects

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

how are you?

I'm following a tutorial from GTCoding [How to Make a Custom Website from Scratch using Wordpress (Theme Development)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KibbYf9avko&t=38s) and I'm on the part of creating the projects page, that is starting at time 3:11:46.

The custom post type is working and I can see it as an option in the dashboard of the page and in the Home page all the post are shown, blogs and projects but, when I'm clicking in the projects page the title of the page shows "Page not found", then ad the body of the page it shows the title for the blogs but not any blog o project. Is important so say that the author created the theme in the way that the blogs page and the projects page loads the content of index.php whose content is the following

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<main>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('/Home');?>">
        <h2 class="page-heading">Todos los Blogs</h2>
    </a>
    <section>
        <?php
            while(have_posts()) {
                the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card Image">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-description">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                </a>
                <div class="card-meta">
                    Posted by <?php the_author(); ?> a las <?php the_time('F j, Y') ?> el
                    <a href="#"><?php echo get_the_category_list(', ') ?></a>
                </div>
                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 30); ?></p>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn-readmore">Leer más</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
            }
            wp_reset_query(); 
        ?>
    </section>
    <div class="pagination">
        <?php echo paginate_links(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

the code for creating the custom post type is in functions.php and is the following

```
<?php

// Adicionando los archivos CSS y JS

function gt_setup() {
    wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts','//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&family=Roboto+Slab:wght@100&family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap');
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome','https://kit.fontawesome.com/5d4742da19.js');
    wp_enqueue_style('style',get_stylesheet_uri(), NULL, microtime(), 'all');
    wp_enqueue_script("main",get_theme_file_uri('/js/main.js'), NULL, microtime(), true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','gt_setup');

// Adding Theme Support

function gt_init() {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_theme_support('title-tag');
    add_theme_support('html5',
        array('commen-list','comment-form','search-form')
    );
}

add_action('after_setup_theme','gt_init');

// Project Post Type

function gt_custom_post_type() {
    register_post_type('project',
        array(
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects'),
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Projects',
            'singular-name' => 'Project',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Project',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Project'
        ),
        'menu-icon' => 'dashicons-clipboard',
        'public' => true,
        'has-archive' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'comments'
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'gt_custom_post_type');
```

the only way I managed to see the projects in the projects page is if I specifically put a while for printing the projects posts, something like the following

```
<?php
    $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'project',
                'post_per_page' => 2
            );
            $projects = new WP_Query($args);
            while($projects->have_posts()) {
                $projects->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card Image">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-description">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                </a>
                <div class="card-meta">
                    Posted by <?php the_author(); ?> a las <?php the_time('F j, Y') ?> el
                    <a href="#"><?php echo get_the_category_list(', ') ?></a>
                </div>
                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 30); ?></p>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn-readmore">Leer más</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
            }
            wp_reset_query(); 
        ?>
```

but then is bad printed because it prints the title of the blogs and the title of the projects in the same page.

The permalinks are working good apparently because if the permalink is clicked or written in the web explorer then the specific project page are loaded, just don't work by loading the projects page.

Update 18/07/21, 14:28:

If a new "Page" is added then when I press the link Porjects in the nav then the page "Projects" loads but without nothing because nothing is configure for that kind of page since the objective is to load the page as a custom post type

Update 19/07/21:

In the following image can be seen the outcome of running the plugin "List All URLs":

IMPORTANT NOTE: I'm not using the default wordpress installation but using Local.

[image: List of all URLs]

How can this be solved?.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The author of that youtube series is unaware of the `pre_get_posts` filter, and is creating brand new queries when they want to change which posts WordPress shows. Instead of asking where you went wrong following the tutorial, try to instead ask about what you're trying to achieve. Also custom post types have their own templates and URLs already, e.g. `archive-project.php` and `/project/`, the registration code even requested archives be created, you don't need a custom `WP_Query` to display them, or a page in the backend

Comment: `wp_reset_query` is only to be used with the `query_posts` function which should never be used. Consider using `wp_rest_postdata` instead which cleans up after `->the_post()`

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell, look, then from the anchors I must call the URL's as the post type and not the slug?. well, I've changed that and the behavior is the same. In addition, currently I know that first wordpress calls archive-project.php and after archive.php, and if those two files aren't found then it calls index.php but right now I have archive.php and archive-project.php but it never call those files, allways calls index.php.

Comment: @TomJNowell  In fact, what the publisher originally does with index.php is for show how wordpress works, after that he explains how to make it with archive.php and archive-project.php, including adn this is the anchor that I have right now to call the projects page: <a href="<?php echo site_url('/project');?>" but it keeps showing  Page not found. If it's any use I'm doing the tutorial on Local for Windows

Comment: This is really confusing. E.g. when you say `/project` I do not know what `/project` is referring to. Do you have a page with the slug `/project` under the pages section of WP Admin? Or a post archive? Did you save your permalinks after adding the project custom post type? I'm not going to spend 3 hours watching a youtube video, you must to make your question self contained. This question is very complicated and unclear. If your goal is how to create a project post type and show a list, ask that instead, it's relatively easy to do in comparison.

Comment: @TomJNowell don't worry, I don't expect you or anyone to see the video, I just put the link as a reference. Look, if you see the code of functions.php it can be seen that is created a custom post type whose name is "project" and the slug of the project posts are "projects", so, when a hiperlink is clicked the page that is loaded is my-page/projects/project-1 for example, the "projects" word comes from the slug at the same custom post type that is registered, so, I don't know what is happening but yes, I have a custom post type called Projects

Comment: @TomJNowell about saving the permalink that I think (read so) just by entering in Settings->Permalinks and saving it then the permalinks will be saved.

Comment: @TomJNowell and yes, my goal is to create a custom post type to show the list of projects in the Projects page (custom post type). Finally, I just installed a plugin called List All URLs to see if the custom post types called under the slug "projects" are and yes, all the post exists so I don't what is happening. I think the website is expecting to see a Page and not a Custom Post Type. I will update my question to show the result that gaves the List All URLs plugin, in that image you can see that the custom post type called "Projects" exists and the "projects" slug also exists

Comment: @TomJNowell so I don't have any idea of why the website doesn't find the custom post types, unless there are a configuration problem that force the site to look for a page instead of a custom post type